# client and server in same nodejs process

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Trying to create an echo server test with both client and server in the same node process.  This code works if I split it into 2 files (server and client) but it does not work if combined into 1 file.  How can I get it to work inside 1 file?

```js
var HOST, createServer, g, net;

net = require("net");

HOST = "127.0.0.1";

createServer = function(port) {
  net.createServer(function(sock) {
    sock.write("welcome!  on port " + port + "\r\n");
    console.log("CONNECTED: " + sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort);
    while (true) {
      sock.write("hello\r\n");
    }
  }).listen(port, HOST);
  console.log("server listening on " + port);
};

createServer(7001);

g = net.createConnection(7001, HOST);

g.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("got " + data);
});
```

and same in coffeescript:

```coffeescript
net = require "net"
HOST = "127.0.0.1"

createServer = (port) ->
  net.createServer((sock) ->
    sock.write("welcome!  on port #{port}\r\n")
    console.log("CONNECTED: #{sock.remoteAddress}:#{sock.remotePort}")
    while true # this is the work queue, what ports to send to...                
      sock.write "hello\r\n"
    return
  ).listen port, HOST
  console.log "server listening on #{port}"
  return

createServer(7001)

# XXX why does g.on "data" never fire?                                           
# this works fine if I move it into                                              
# it's own file, how to co-exist                                                 
# this client with server above                                                  
# in same file?                                                                  
g = net.createConnection(7001, HOST)
g.on "data", (data) ->
  console.log "got #{data}"
  return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true) {
  sock.write("hello\r\n");
}
```

This is your problem. You're writing to the stream indefinitely; and if it never ends, it won't trigger your "data" event. To illustrate more clearly, try this (in the place of the code above):

```
while (true) {
  console.log("hello!");
  sock.write("hello\r\n");
}
```

Or:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  i++;
  sock.write("hello\r\n");
}
```

EDIT:
To keep echoing indefinitely, perhaps try something like this:

```
net.createServer(function(sock) { 
  sock.write("welcome!  on port " + port + "\r\n");
  console.log("CONNECTED: " + sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort);
  setInterval(function() {
    sock.write("hello\r\n");
  }, 2000);
}).listen(port, HOST);
```

Comment: Thanks bardzusny!  I used SetInterval with a delay of "0"  and data is now pumping through!